# Ambiguous documentation for Apache Zookeeper setup

Tags: logging, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

At this link, [Official Zookeeper doc](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#The+Log+Directory), I find the quote ambiguous.

> ZooKeeper stores its data in a data directory and its transaction log in a transaction log directory. By default these two directories are the same. The server can (and should) be configured to store the transaction log files in a separate directory than the data files. Throughput increases and latency decreases when transaction logs reside on a dedicated log devices.

It says that transaction log files should store the transaction logs in a separate directory. Then it says that a dedicated device is optimal? Why is the default to store the data directory files and the transaction log files in the same location? I believe I am confused because I may not understand what they mean by "directory". I think of folder when I hear directory. Do they mean hardware storage device when they say directory? I would not expect throughput to increase and latency to decrease if these files are stored on the same device but in different folders. I would expect throughput to increase and latency to decrease if the files are stored on a different device.

Am I interpreting their documentation correctly? No performance gains will be made from simply storing the transaction logs and data files in separate folders. They only mean that those gains will be had if they are stored on different hardware storage devices correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The main point is to have the transaction log on a dedicated device, because ZooKeeper needs to fsync to that disk. Any latencies on this part may cause serious issues.

From ZK configuration perspective, separate directories is just a prerequisite to make this possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what can happen when an fsync occurs? I found this explanation of fsync, http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync, but I am curious about what the issue will look like. Will I get crashes? Just bad performance at times? I just don't know what to expect.

Comment: Fsync is a very costly operation - making sure data is flushed to disk. If something else is using the same disk, fsync can take a long time. Since a ZooKeeper instance needs to make sure a transaction is written to disk before confirming the write, this makes fsync a part of the critical path for a ZK write. There is an option to disable this (forceSync=false), in which case zk will not wait for fsync. However, this might brake some of the core guaranties ZK offers.

Comment: By breaking guarantees, does that mean the durability and ability to recover state? In my application, I am much more worried about performance and crashes are tolerable in that there is no "lost data", we simply recompute a result on restart. It sounds like I should disable forceSync in my case. Is this a naive assumption on my part though? Could there be other concerns related to disabling forceSync?

Comment: I wouldn't be going disabling fsync before you are sure it is an issue. It can be an issue in virtualized environments like in AWS or when ZK is sharing the machine with heavy disk users. The way to fix it is not disabling fsync, but giving zk a dedicated disk. Disabling fsync would mean you could loose acknowledged writes, which might cause transient or sporadic failures/bugs, hard to trace and debug. I would try searching a bit for stories about this sort of issues.

Comment: @igorbel Wow, that's crazy to read. Now I'm happy that I chose to handle my own zookeeper cluster instead of going to pre-baked solutions. Has the situation improved in the meantime? I guess AWS must be aware of such scenarios and has improved their infrastructure since this answer was written.